# Django: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ObjectId'

Tags: python, django, serialization, jsonresponse

Im getting this type error when trying to return a JsonResponse. In the code `python_serializer` is an object that has a instance variable named data containing the results of the `JsonParser().parse(request)` which is of type dictionary(in python). Later in the code when I try to return a json response my program keep giving me this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ObjectId'`

Here is the full traceback:

`Internal Server Error: /api/products
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\MongoDBClone\DjangoRestApi\Product\views.py", line 29, in product_list
    return JsonResponse(product_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 562, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 529, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "C:\Users\alexei\Columns\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 994, in to_representation
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ObjectId'`

Product Model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    partNumber = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='defaultPartNum')
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, default='Default Description')
```

``

Serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

``

View :

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def product_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        products = Product.objects.all()
        searchedPartnum = request.GET.get('partNumber', None)
        if searchedPartnum is not None:
            products = products.filter(searchedPartnum__icontains=searchedPartnum)

        productSearializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(productSearializer.data, safe=False)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    product_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    product_serializer = ProductSerializer(data=product_data)
    if product_serializer.is_valid():
        product_serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(product_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return JsonResponse(product_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

elif request.METHOD == 'DELETE':
    count = Product.objects.all().delete()
    return JsonResponse({'message': '{} Products were deleted'.format(count[0])}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: I think you should go for using Response rather than JsonResponse

Comment: from rest_framework.response import Response

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/ follow this tutorial

Comment: @SahilDesai i just tried it. It gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongo as backend then django is creating a id field automatically for you
the id field is of type Varchar or ObjectId.
but the serializer does not know that and is trying to create IntegerField type that's why you got this error